# ¿Error de tipo de datos en C++?

Tags: c++

Buenas tardes colegas,

Tengo una duda sobre como estoy planteando la solución a un problema que tiene el siguiente pseudocodigo y sus correspondientes respuestas:

```
function puzzle(N) {

.A = 1

.B = 1

.C = 1

.D = 1

.repeat N times {

....X = D + 2 * C + 3 * B + 4 * A

....A = B

....B = C

....C = D

....D = X

.}

return D % 10000000000 // últimos 10 dígitos de D

}

print puzzle(10)

print puzzle(100)

print puzzle(pow(2022, 100)) // 2022 elevado a la 100

(los puntos son para identación)

====== Output ======

30520

720820623

???
```

Mi código en C++ es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int i;
    int x;    

int puzzle(int n){
    
    int  a = 1,
         b = 1,
         c = 1, 
         d = 1;  

    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        
        x = d + 2*c + 3*b + 4*a;
        
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = d;
        d = x;
        
        cout << x << "\n";
        //printf("%d",x);
        //putchar('\n');
    }
    
    //printf("%d",d);getch();
    //printf("\n");
    
    return d % 10000000000;

}

int main(){

    printf("Presiona una tecla para ver el resultado con n = 10:" "\n");
    getch();
    cout << puzzle(10);
    //printf("%d", puzzle(10));
    getch();
    printf("\n");

    printf("Presiona una tecla para ver el resultado con n = 100:" "\n");
    getch();
    cout << puzzle(100);
    //printf("%d", puzzle(100));
    printf("\n");
    getch();
/*
    printf("Presiona una tecla para ver el resultado con n = 2022 a la 100:" "\n");
    getch();
    printf("%d", puzzle(pow(2022, 100)));
    printf("\n");
    getch();
*/  
}
```

No puedo lograr el resultado de Puzzle(100) como ven, por ende tampoco he probado el tercer resultado, he probado los resultados con long int , y con unsigned long int, y no puedo llegar al valor 720820623 que solicita el ejercicio, alguna sugerencia o como resolver el problema?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Usa el tipo `unsigned long long`, y el sufijo `ull` en valores grandes para indicar su tipo explícitamente, como `10000000000ull`.

Comment: Muchas gracias @don_aman, aun así no logro llegar al valor solicitado 720820623, en su lugar estoy obteniendo 6523682191 con n=100

Comment: También habría que ver cómo funciona el ciclo en el código original. Puede que la condición sea `i <= n`

Comment: Lo estaba resolviendo, pero no creo se pueda a través de código, lograste llegar a algo? me suena que hay que llegar a una función para determinar el resultado que pide para la func puzzle(2022 elevado a la 100)

Answer (score 2):

El tipo de un dato nos indica el rango de valores que puede almacenar, los datos habitualmente disponibles en C++ tienen los siguientes tamaños:

| Tamaño (en bits) | Valores almacenables |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 2<sup>8</sup>=256 |
| 16 | 2<sup>16</sup>=65536 |
| 32 | 2<sup>32</sup>=4294967296 |
| 64 | 2<sup>64</sup>=18446744073709551616 |

Esos tamaños se relacionan con los siguientes tipos:

| Tamaño (en bits) | Tipo |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | `char` |
| 16 | `short` |
| 32 | `int` |
| 64 | `long long` |

Y a su vez, cada tipo puede ser con signo (`signed`) o sin signo (`unsigned`); en el caso de los datos con signo la mitad de los valores almacenables se usan para números negativos y la otra mitad para positivos.

Una vez sabido esto, el mayor número positivo almacenable estará en una variable de 64 bits sin signo, cuyo tipo será `unsigned long long`; si cambias todos los `int` de tu función `puzzle` por ese tipo:

```
using Int = unsigned long long;

Int i;
Int x;    

Int puzzle(Int n)
{
    Int  a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d = 1;  

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        x = d + 2*c + 3*b + 4*a;
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = d;
        d = x;

        cout << x << "\n";
    }
    
    return d % 10000000000ull;
}
```

Las últimas líneas de la salida se parecerán a:

> ```
> Presiona una tecla para ver el resultado con n = 100:
> 10
> 19
> 46
> 118
> 307
> 757
> 1909
> 4816
> 12133
> 30520
> 76870
> 193573
> 487405
> 1227241
> 3090250
> 7781239
> 19593082
> ...
> ...
> 2193875795870888222
> 15956854094594396005
> 575419844515818117
> 26354040185858793
> 2483026975355581082
> 12749178746523682191
> 6523682191
> ```

La última línea muestra un valor pequeño porque la operación [desborda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) el valor máximo de un entero de 64 bits sin signo y provoca que el valor *se de la vuelta*.